# Use Case Diagram - customer registration by manager

Tags: uml, use-case, uml-designer

The system I want to model is an application called GetKnowSoft. The example is simple: there is a customer, a manager, and a register customer use case. Who registers the customer in the application is the manager.

I connect the manager to the client. The question is: Do I also tie the customer to the use case, even though the customer has no active role?

Answer (score 1):

If the customer doesn’t directly interact with the app, it should not be an actor.

If the customer would have some interactions (e.g. enters name and address that is validated by the manager, or receives a confirmation email from the app) then it should be an actor.